# As3 a different if-case

Tags: actionscript-3

When i use following:

```
var child:DisplayObjectContainer = dso.getChildAt( dso.numChildren -1 ) as DisplayObjectContainer;
trace(child); // [object MenuView]
```

My question now is if i want to use a if-case to see that it really is MenuView... something like:

```
if( child == 'MenuView'){...
```

I can not figure it out how to set such if case into work :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**is**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f65) operator:

```
if( child is MenuView){
```

**Update:** If importing `MenuView` class is impossible in your case, then you can try to use [**describeType**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) global function:

```
//if 'MenuView' class does not have 'namespace'
if( describeType(child).@name == "MenuView" ){ 

//if 'MenuView' class does have 'namespace'
if( describeType(child).@name.indexOf('MenuView') !== -1 ){
```

Comment: Already tested, but since i have no access to MenuView itself from anywhere, i get 1120 error with: Access of undefined property MenuView

Comment: @DanelK You need to import `MenuView` class.

Comment: Thats the problem, i dont have access to it since it is used in another SWF which im loading into mine with Loader. OR im not aware of how i could get hold of it from in-loaded swf :S

Comment: Ohh, allmost... Your update worked. Tho i had to add entire classpath to it! Thanx!

Comment: you could also just use getQualifiedClassName

Comment: @Engineer that's correct code, and gets the job done, but I can add by own stupid class that's called MenuView, so you should rather go for the full class path

Comment: @RasmusWriedtLarsen I am aware of such things ).I am trying to provide the answer which will completely work for OP.That is why I have changed my code.